# Get Kubernetes ClusterIP address in NodeJs App

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

Hi I have a simple k8s ClusterIP Service for Kafka:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka-app
  ports:
    - name: kafka-app
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
```

and in my Nodejs application container, I am trying to get the value:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: subscriber
      image: uk1987/subscriber
      env:
        - name: KAFKA_URL
          value: kafka-srv:9092 # Reference to kafka-service
```

so that I can use it in my broker like:

```
this.kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: "kafka-app",
    brokers: [process.env.KAFKA_URL] //# Accessing kafka-service value
});
```

`process.env.KAFKA_URL` instead of giving me the address of the kafka-srv e.g. 10.0.12.94, it is giving me the literal value of `kafka-srv:9092`.
Can someone guide me how to get the address of kafka-srv IP?

Comment: Why do you need to use the IP? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: I don't need to use IP, I just want kafka-srv to resolve to broker in my nodejs application.

Comment: It will, assuming your app label selector is correct. See above docs. What exact error are you getting otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct method to inject a `Service`'s IP address instead of host name. The reason is that the IP is allocated to the service automatically on it's creation by default. You can assign the IP [manually](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/05/23/service-ip-dynamic-and-static-allocation/) to the `Service` but it's not recommended approach.

Also it is better to use host name instead of IP because IP can change anytime e.g during Service recreation. Host name on the other hand remains fix. Basically it's the same principal as the one found in your normal website's DNS concept.

One way to get the IP address of a host name in your case is to use [dns](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns) library of `nodejs` to resolve the it within the application. Example:

```js
const dns = require('node:dns');

dns.lookup('example.org', (err, address, family) => {
  console.log('address: %j family: IPv%s', address, family);
});
// address: "93.184.216.34" family: IPv4
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are just strings. They don't resolve DNS requests.

You can use `kubectl get svc/kafka-srv` and copy from that, but that probably won't help you access the Kafka broker.

Note: I recommend you use something like Strimzi to run Kafka in Kubernetes. https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/